# How to Create a 3 column by 8 row column GUI with Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with Tkinter with the following layout. I have tried creating by myself, but had some problems with Widgets dynamically adjusting itself based on the things inside the widget.

The format I want to achieve is as follows:[image]

I want to make a 3 column by 8 row grid, in which I can place various type of widgets.

To explain further, each **green** section is a buttons that will call different functions (6 individual buttons on the left).  These functions will be displayed in the **blue** area (which in fact will be one whole area 6row x 2col fused into 1 big area and *should not adjust based on the text size* i.e. `main_window.grid_propagate(False)` ).
The **orange**, will be fused together to have a logo, and the **purple**, **yellow**, **grey**  and **pink**, areas be inidividual items.

So essentially it will be become so:
[image]

**Note:** *Where "Main Window" is a window that is able to display various widgets and text size **without** readjusting/reconfiguring the whole windows resolution.*

The blue area will in time be show buttons, texts, images, etc based on one of the six buttons pressed on it's left hand side.

**Q:** How can I initially create a 8row x 3col grid, in which I can place widgets. and fuse the blue area into one, where I can have display texts, images, etc based on the subroutine from the one of the 6 buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what difficulty you are facing, because this is just about as simple a layout as you can create. The only question is what you want to happen when the window is resized. Do the buttons grow, or does the colored part stay the same and the extra space is added as a blank area to the right and bottom? Or, some combination of the two?

You'll still have the problem that when widgets resize, they affect the things around them. That's how tkinter works, and arguably how it *should* work. If a widget gets bigger, you still need to see the whole widget.

Here's an example which allocates all extra space evenly among the rows and columns. You can control this with the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` methods at the end of the example.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.logo = tk.Label(self, text="Logo", background="orange")
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(6):
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self, text="Button %s" % (i+1,), background="green"))
        self.other1 = tk.Label(self, background="purple")
        self.other2 = tk.Label(self, background="yellow")
        self.other3 = tk.Label(self, background="pink")
        self.other4 = tk.Label(self, background="gray")
        self.main = tk.Frame(self, background="blue")

        self.logo.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.other1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.other2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.other3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.other4.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[0].grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[1].grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[2].grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[3].grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[4].grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttons[5].grid(row=7, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.main.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=6)

        for row in range(8):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
        for col in range(3):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's fantastic! One question, how can I readjust the size (width) of the buttons with ( I have tried `pady=0` and `width=0`, it didn't decrease the width at all, and make the width static) so irrespective of the font size within the button the button doesn't widen?

Comment: @3kstc: I don't understand your question. If you want wider buttons, just give them an explicit width (eg: `Button(..., width=40)`).  Pay close attention to the answer, and notice how it says it allocates extra space equally, so if you want the leftmost column to _not_ expand, don't give it a weight.

Comment: Based on the code above, how do I update (a) 'cell'(s) when a button is pushed? For example when I click `Button 1` I want the Pink cell to be updated with text "Button 1" and also display some text in the blue [main window] cell (with the text size is 16)?

Comment: @3kstc: I don't understand the question. Just read the documentation on the Label widget. `self.other3.configure(text="Button1")`, and you have to put some sort of widget in the main area.

Comment: @BrylanOakley After reading more about Tkinter and structure, I have better understanding, but I cannot get the `main` ("Main Window") `Frame` to appear blue. The [output](https://s31.postimg.org/if4j324hn/output.jpg) I have from the code above does not have a blue background.